# Расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Любимого мужа Василия моей лучшей подруги Ларисы от души и от всего сердца поздравляю с днём рождения

Comment: Василия, любимого мужа моей лучшей подруги Ларисы, сердечно, от всей души поздравляю с Днём рождения.

Comment: Хорошо изменили, shampar, приплюсовал бы, но почему "день" с большой буквы?

Answer (score 2):

Запятые не нужны, а "от души и от всего сердца" — неоправданный плеоназм.

Answer (score 0):

Любимого мужа Василия моей лучшей подруги Ларисы от души и от всего сердца поздравляю с днём рождения. Запятые здесь не нужны, потому что от словосочетания  "мужа Василия" задаём вопрос КОГО?(имея в виду ЧЕЙ муж) к "моей лучшей подруги Ларисы". И будет это дополнением, и обособляться не будет. Или несогласованным определением, и тоже обособляться не будет. А вот если бы ставился вопрос от "мужа Василия" КАКОГО?, тогда это было бы обособленным определением и выделялось бы запятыми. Например, Василия, любимого мужа моей лучшей подруги Ларисы,... Здесь ставится вопрос КАКОГО? или  уточняется КАКОГО ИМЕННО?